# pass variable into .ready(function)

Tags: ajax, geolocation, document-ready

I have a function for finding lat and lng co-ordinates for user:

```
function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("out");

  if (!navigator.geolocation){
    output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
    return;
  }

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";

    output.appendChild(img);
  }

  function error() {
    output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  }

  output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```

I want to be able to pass the lat and lng values into my ajax request.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.submitLocation').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url:
```

The problem is I don't know how to pass into the ajax request when it is inside the .ready function. (The .click function is for when user enters a search term but adding geolocation means this is not necessary so I will be altering it to something like: if latitute is not null do x else .click(function)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating another function with another ajax request inside to deal with requests by lat and lng.

```
function geoFindMe() {

        function success(position) {
        var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&units=metric" + "&APPID=ID",
            type: "GET",
```